# How to remove the blue action bar in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am creating an android app but I have some problem I cant remove this blue heading or I don’t know how its called, or action bar ?
I have tried some methods but they didn’t work.
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#9AEA30">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/discount"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show us your layout XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to remove it is to make your `Activity` extend the `Activity` class and not the `AppCompatActivity`.

That is do something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

}
```

Comment: This is a bad solution. He might want to use other AppCompat functionality even if he doesn't want an ActionBar.

Comment: I know it is. As i said in the answer, it is the easiest solution. But if the OP doesn't want to use the ActionBar, there is no purpose of using the AppCompatActivity from the way i see it.

Answer (score 3):

What did you try?

Just add this in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
```

And

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` in `application` section.

Answer (score 1):

In your style file (res/values/styles.xml) is declared the style of your project.

For example

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

Change "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"  with "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

like this

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

The same can be achieved for Dark themes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Android Studio, you'll have a choice to change the Theme from the preview windows without any code.

Answer (score 0):

This method work for me :

Remove this code from following activity_main.xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Answer (score 0):

may be late but i found a way too just remove the following code from your xml layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest and cleanest solution IMO:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
```